# Preserve New Document ID when copying to another site

Tags: document-id

I need to copy documents from Site A to Site B (Document ID has been turn on)

Site A, contains documents that users edit countless times before the documents are copied (publish) to Site B. Site B only contain documents the have been copied (published) by the users.

When I copy a document in Site A with Document ID "Site A - 1" is copied (published) the first time to Site B it receives a New Document ID it "Site B - 1". So far so good! The second time the same document is copied (Published) the Document's Document ID is replaced with "Site A - 1" instead of preserving the original "Site B - 1" Document ID .

How can I preserve the Document ID no mater the countless times I Copied (Publish) to site B?  Is this doable. Can the Document ID be updated at all?